# jq to change a specific field value by select

Tags: json, select, updates, jq

I have a project.json file and its contents look like this:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/unpackaged"
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/untracked"
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/zipsc",
            "package": "ZipSC",
            "versionName": "Version 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorId":"oldValue",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/unpackaged/open-cti",
            "package": "OpenCTI",
            "versionName": "Ver 0.3",
            "versionNumber": "0.3.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorId": "04t1P000000cB425QAE",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
    "namespace": "ZAR",
    "packageAliases": {
        "ZAR": "0Ho1P000000XZA4SAO",
        "OpenCTI": "0Ho1P000000X3AvSAO"
    }
}
```

I want to change the ancestorId field for the packageDirectory objects where default is true. In that case oldValue in the example should become newValue. The output should be as follows. How do I do this with jq on a shell script.

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/unpackaged"
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/untracked"
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/zipsc",
            "package": "ZipariSC",
            "versionName": "Version 0.1",
            "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorId":"newValue",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sfdx-source/unpackaged/open-cti",
            "package": "OpenCTI",
            "versionName": "Ver 0.3",
            "versionNumber": "0.3.0.NEXT",
            "ancestorId": "04t1P000000cB425QAE",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
    "namespace": "ZAR",
    "packageAliases": {
        "ZAR": "0Ho1P000000XZA4SAO",
        "OpenCTI": "0Ho1P000000X3AvSAO",
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you point out explicitly what is supposed to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use an if-then-else expression for it, not select.

```
.packageDirectories |= map(
  if .default == true
  then .ancestorId = "newValue"
  else . end
)
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/jUcbQ5il7e)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

FYPI, there is a way to achieve the goal using `select`:

```
.packageDirectories[] |=
  ((select(.default == true) | .ancestorId = "newValue") // . )
```